# Verify array with custom objects

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I have a class:

```
public class MyCustomObject {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
}
```

And I've created array of **MyCustomObject**:

```
MyCustomObject[] array = new MyCustomObject[]{new MyCustomObject()};
```

My goal is to verify elements of this array using hamcrest matchers. I've tried the following approach:

```
assertThat(array, allOf(hasItemInArray(hasProperty("field1", equalTo("value1")))), hasItemInArray(hasProperty("field2", equalTo("value2")))));
```

But unfortunatly it does not work.

In which way the array of **custom objects** can be verified?

Comment: What exactly does not work? What would you expect? When you say capacity, do you mean the size/length of the Array? If so, why not check for that?

Comment: I cannot verify what elements contain array with my custom objects. The idea is to verify name and value fields directly with class specified above.

Comment: This is not a good design. The whole idea of hamcrest and BDD in general is that the tests read like specifications. This reads like you are doing checks of class metadata rather than what the class does.

Comment: I am not sure that understand your point. In general I have array of org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader that I am going to set to my restful client. My goals is to verify whether array contains correct values before client will be called with junit test. The idea was to implement this using hamcrest as it is really readable. But unfortunatly this approach does not work in my case. I am new in hamcrest, and it's possible that I've made some mistakes in my assert. Will be good if you recomended much more suite library for such things .

Comment: If you want a verification, do not use hamcrest. Check your constraints with if and instanceof, throw Exceptions if they are not met. Hamcrest and Junit are for unit testing, not runtime parameter verification.

Comment: Can you please clarify "it does not work"? Compiler error? False positive/negative? In this case (toy code) you should split that into two assertions.

Comment: The assert statement does not compile, remove a closing bracket after `"value1"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your array to an `ArrayList` just for testing purposes:

```
List<MyCustomObject> customObjects = Arrays.asList(array);
```

And then assert with the Hamcrest `hasItems` Matcher if the expected items are present in the list:

```
assertThat(customObjects, hasItems(myCustomObject1, myCustomObject2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding getters to your class? That did the trick for me.

```
public class MyCustomObject {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
}
```